# Specifying filename dynamically in OPENROWSET

Tags: c#, sql

Requirement : Get the binary format of the PDF file.
working code:
When I specify the filename in the query it works fine. But I need to pass the filename dynamically to query.
(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Manjunath\a.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB)

output: 0x255044462D312E340D0A25

Error : But when we try to send the filename dynamically ,getting below error. Please help on this.
**Cannot bulk load. The file " + strFullFileName + " does not exist or you don't have file access rights..**
Code snippet:
strFullFileName is of string datatype where we are passing full path of PDF.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
 string query = "SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' + strFullFileName + ', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB";
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
 connection.Open();
 success = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you put variable inside string, please try the following:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
string query = "SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '"+ strFullFileName + "', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
connection.Open();
success = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I am getting below output 
0xFFFFFFFF

Actual output should be different
0x255044462D312E340D0A25

Comment: can you print query variable and see the sql query that you have

Comment: When I print the query ,it's correct.

I am trying to insert the output of that query to table of  Column -contents which is of datattype (varbinary(max)).





   while (reader.Read())                    {                       
var  BulkColumn = (Byte)reader.GetValue(0);                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contents", Convert.ToBase64String(BulkColumn.ToString()));       
             }
I'm getting error when executing sql reader and fetching . please help on this

Error : Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: can you please add the whole code to the question